# vim: replace a line pattern by a no line

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to achieve a simple substitution on vim but can't get it right. I need to remove, on an entire file, all the lines that match a pattern. The pattern is "something*", meaning "something" followed by anything until the end of the line.
I tried `:%s/pattern*\n//g` and `:%s/pattern*$//g`without success.
Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: FYI: The * applies to the previous character in your pattern, so in your case it will match zero or more n's.

Comment: Right, I always get confused with shell expansion characters :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:g` instead of `:substitute`.

```
:g/pattern/d
```

would remove all the lines that match with pattern.

As for the pattern, yours will match `patter`, `pattern`, `patternn` and so on. Use the wildcard `.` to match any characters. So your regexp should be `pattern.*$` --- but if you wish to remove the lines entirely, the `:g/pattern/d` does the trick fine.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, gotta get used to read more manuals! ;)

Comment: @brafales, yeah. `:g` is the other half of the `ex` magic. :) A true hidden powerhouse that can do interesting tricks.

Comment: One addition: `g/pattern/d _` (note the underscore) will act just the same as `s/.*pattern.*\n\=//g`, while your version will spoil values in unnamed, numbered (1-9) and, probably, some other registers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of `vim` you're using, you may have trouble with what I'm going to propose:

```
:%s/pattern.*^V^M//g
```

For `^V`, literally hit `ctrl-v`, followed by the `ENTER` (^M) key.  `^V` lets you enter a literal character without it interpreting the character.

Comment: Dot means «any symbol except newline», so no need to use such collection.